# Visual Studio Xamarin - Problem building realease iOS project with webservice

Tags: ios, visual-studio, web-services, xamarin

I'm experiencing an error when trying to build a release iphone app and I've noticed it has to do with Web Service. It only happens when I add a Web reference.

The target framework is .NET Standard 2.0 and I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

The error is the following:

> 1>SGEN : error : Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' ou uma de suas dependências. Falha na validação de nome forte. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

It happens with all the projects I've tested. Has anyone gone through this as well?

I've created a Xamarin Web Forms project and didn't add any code on it, just configured all the info in order to build the app. It worked fine. I've added a Web reference to consume my `webservice` and it gave me that error when I tried to build the project. Is it a problem with the `System.web.service.dll`?

Answer (score 1):

`System.web.service` does not exist for NetStd2, you can not arbitrarily add manual assembly references (especially ones that are based off of the .Net Framework).

You can add a reference to the pre-existing Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android versions within the platform native projects (not .NetStd2 ones).

- Xamarin.iOS References:

[image]

- Xamarin.Android References:

[image]

And then access it from .NetStd2 via a Forms' dependency service:

- [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering! I think I didn't explain very well what I'm doing, because what you said is exactly what I'm doing. I'm not adding a reference to the Xamarin forms project, I added the "web reference" to both my platforms native projects and I'm using the dependency service. This is what I did: created an empty Xamarin forms project, added all the provisioning information in order to publish the app, added a "web reference" to both my android and iOS projects and tried to run the iOS project. That's when I get that error (before adding the web reference it worked fine).